# ORDER BY date SQL with LEFT JOIN for messaging

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, sql-order-by

I have a problem that seems to be simple to solve but is not.

I have a MySQl database that storeS user, and chat sessions and chat lines of users.

Here's a part of UML schema of my database:

[image: uml schema]

In chat_sessions we store only all session id (Auto increment)
In chat_sessions_members we store all of the user session
In chat_lines we store all line of the chat_sessions

Example:

[image: Table data]

The problem is how to get session of specific user and at the same time get the last lines if exist.

My last try gives me this code:

```sql
SELECT `chat_sessions_members`.`session_id`, ANY_VALUE(`send_at`) AS `send_at`, ANY_VALUE(`line`) AS `line`
FROM `chat_sessions_members`
LEFT JOIN `chat_lines` ON `chat_sessions_members`.`session_id` = `chat_lines`.`session_id`
WHERE `user_id` = '1'
GROUP BY `session_id`
ORDER BY DATE(`send_at`) DESC
```

But it's not an ordered reply.

I know a lot of post talk about that but I don't understand all of them.

Comment: You don't say what you want returned, how output is a function of input. This is unclear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. Please don't **yell**.Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the last (most recent) line for each session that has a given user.  If so, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the last line and `LEFT JOIN` to identify the user:

```
SELECT cl.*
FROM chat_sessions_members csm LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT cl.*, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cl.session_id ORDER BY cl.send_at DESC) as seqnum
      FROM chat_lines cl
     ) cl
     ON cl.session_id = csm.session_id AND seqnum = 1
WHERE csm.user_id = 1
ORDER BY DATE(cl.send_at) DESC;
```

Comment: it works thank you very much! I really thought my subject was unreadable
In the future you will be able to explain this request? it can be helped several people